# Sound in VLC is out of sync

Tags: 11.04, sound, vlc

After a minute or so all my sounds in different videos and formats gets late.

I've tried to reinstall VLC but it didn't help. 
Please help I can't play any videos because of that.

It's late about 1-2 seconds.

All of the videos work perfectly in movie player!

Comment: Have you tried resetting vlc, either internally or via a purge?

Comment: no, so please tell me how to!

Comment: To purge do `sudo apt-get purge vlc` and then reinstall. You might want to purge other vlc packages before reinstall too, e.g. vlc-data. I'm not sure if this helps but it will remove vlc as well as its configuration files.

Comment: To reset vlc choose Tools - Settings - Reset settings or the like.

Comment: to purge and then install didn't work...

Comment: no that didn't work...

Comment: @Alvar How did reset work?

Comment: don't know how to. or what it is?

Comment: ALSA worked for me for most videos. I found one video of all that I tried that had no audio after the switch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

VLC and audio lag issues are perhaps more common than they really should be.  Under Linux, pulse-audio seems to be a common thread.

However there doesnt appear to be a magic "fix" to cure all.

So here are a few things you could try:

1. Check that you haven't changed the Audio synchronisation: Tools - Track Synchronisation should be set to zero
2. Check that other preferences havent affected audio tracking: Tools > Preferences and click the Reset Preferences button
3. Use Alsa instead of Pulse-Audio for output:  From the VLC menu, choose Tools > Preferences > Audio. Change the Output from `Default` to `Alsa`
4. If using Natty - revert to using interrupt driven mode instead of time-scheduled mode

   modify the following line in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

   `load-module module-udev-detect`

   with :

   `load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0`

Use Alsa instead of Pulse-Audio for output: From the VLC menu, choose Tools > Preferences > Audio. Change the Output from Default to Alsa
^ This works

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested to increase the Caching value?
It helped to increase it from 300 to 1000 for me.
If you stream the files via samba you can increase it under the SMB Access Module.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After todays update to the 1.1.12 version of VLC and using Ubuntu 11.10. Most if not all out of sync problems are gone.

Users need to update their Ubuntu to the latest daily updates which should provide the latest version of VLC (the 1.1.12 version). Already tested and all movies I have seen are working correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I've had exactly the same problem for the last few weeks.

Although I don't have a fix there is a remedy in the menu. I go to **Tools > Track Synchronization**. This opens a new window. Under the **Synchronization** tab you'll find **Audio/Video** - *Advance of audio over video* - with a window and up and down arrows to offset the audio. I found arrowing -.003 or -.002 seconds is usually pretty close and watchable.

Even though this fixes it enough to watch videos for now, I hope future updates will fix the problem.

Comment: this isn't a fix this is a workaround, and it's not that good...

Comment: just trying to help, man

Comment: There were a bunch of VLC updates today. Hopefully that'll fix the problem.